# Two network interfaces with same metric and with gateway. Which one is used?

Tags: networking, routing

Suppose I have a system with two network interfaces. These are in different subnets and have a different local IP address. Both have a gateway defined, and both have the same metric value in the routing table.

If I send a package to an external IP address (an IP address which is not in any of the subnets), how does the system choose the network interface that sends the package?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, [How does Linux choose between default gateways?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337332/86440) has relevant information.

Comment: This comment: `the order of the default route statements determined which interface was always used` explains how two network interfaces were set up in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/310595). Maybe it explains what you ask.