# Route blocking incoming traffic

Tags: rhel, route, traffic

I have a problem on my Redhat computer.

I do have incoming traffic on a network interface, let's call it **eth1**.
I also have outgoing traffic on another network interface, let's call it **eth2**.

When the route for outgoing traffic is not set, incoming traffic is correctly received on **eth1** (a program is using information contained in this incoming flow), and, obviously, outgoing traffic from **eth2** is not correctly routed since the route is not set.

When I set the route for **eth2**, my outgoing traffic is now correctly routed and there is no problem here.
But incoming traffic on **eth1** is not received anymore!
It is very curious because I don't see how a route can block incoming traffic.

When using Wireshark on **eth1**, I see that packets are still received. When using Netcat, nothing is received.

If I delete the route, Netcat now receive the incoming traffic and everything works fine, but outgoing **eth2** traffic is not routed anymore and I need this packets to be routed.

Is there a route mechanism I don't understand?

Comment: Show us the routes you are adding and src & dst IPs of this incoming traffic.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, disabling reverse path filtering solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Christopher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29678/christopher) said:

> Does this information help? Maybe not the same scenario, but probably relevant. 
>   [Separate Network Traffic on Two Network Interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200188/separate-network-traffic-on-two-network-interfaces)

This helped as disabling reverse path filtering solved this issue.